# Java skipping a line of code? VERY basic java

Tags: java

If you look at the line of code where it says

```
System.out.println("Please enter the firstname of your favourite female author");
mFirstName = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("Please enter her second name");
mSurname = scanner.nextLine();
```

It completely skips the firstname part and goes straight to surname? Any ideas why this is happenimh?

```
import java.util.*;
    'class university{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            Person2 mPerson, fPerson;

        String fFirstName, fSurname, mFirstName, mSurname;
        int fAge, mAge;

        System.out.println("Please enter the firstname of your favourite female author");
        fFirstName = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter her second name");
        fSurname = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter her age");
        fAge = scanner.nextInt();
         System.out.println("Please enter the firstname of your favourite female author");
         mFirstName = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter her second name");
        mSurname = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter her age");
        mAge = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print(fPerson);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is likely caused by the `scanner.nextInt`, which will leave a new line character in the stream, which is then being picked by the next `scanner.nextLine`.  Try adding a `scanner.nextLine` call BEFORE the next question

Answer (score 2):

Add a `nextLine()` call after you call `nextInt()`. Because `nextInt()` doesn't finish the line. So the next call to `nextLine()` will return an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

`fAge = scanner.nextInt();` does not consume the line ending.

add `scanner.nextLine()` after that to absorb the end-of-line character and it will work.